# Creating an updatable d3 donut chart using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dataset, donut-chart

For this problem, I am attempting to create a donut chart by importing my JSON file locally onto my code. The JSON file contains an array of objects with hospitals and etc. And so, I am using the d3.nest() operator to group my data by individual hospitals (This means that each donut chart represents a particular hospital). The design of the chart is that each path of the donut chart is a particular type of diagnosis that a patient has received. For example, there is a count of 20 cases of chest pain.

The part that I am struggling with is that after I used the d3.nest() operator, the donut chart isn't created. I am not too sure what is wrong unless I have to add additional code for the nest or not.

I know that eventually I will be using a dropdown menu to choose a unique hospital.

The example of the donut chart that I'm trying to follow is this website:https://bl.ocks.org/tezzutezzu/c2653d42ffb4ecc01ffe2d6c97b2ee5e

Below is my code and other attachments:

1.) JavaScript

```
  d3.json("file.json", function(error, dataset) {

    if (error) throw error;

    //Group data by individual hospital
    var infoByHospitals = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.hospitalName })
    .entries(dataset);

     var width = 800;
     var height = 800;

     var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
     var donutWidth = 100; 

    var legendRectSize = 25; 
    var legendSpacing = 6;  


    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

    var svg = d3.select('#chart') 
    .append('svg') 
    .attr('width', width)  
    .attr('height', height) 
    .append('g') 
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')'); 

    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth) 
    .outerRadius(radius); 

    var pie = d3.pie() 
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; }) 
    .sort(null); 

     infoByHospitals.forEach(function(d) {
     d.count = +d.count;
     d.enabled = true; 
 });

    var path = svg.selectAll('path') 
    .data(pie(infoByHospitals)) 
    .enter()
    .append('path') 
    .attr('d', arc) 
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.diagnosis); })
    .each(function(d) { this._current - d; });


    var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend') 
    .data(color.domain()) 
    .enter() 
    .append('g') 
    .attr('class', 'legend') 
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing; 
        var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2; 
        var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset; 
        return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
    });
    legend.append('rect')                                    
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)                        
    .attr('height', legendRectSize) 
    .style('fill', color) 
    .style('stroke', color) 
    .on('click', function(label) {
        var rect = d3.select(this); 
        var enabled = true;
        var totalEnabled = d3.sum(infoByHospitals.map(function(d) { 
            return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0; 
        }));
        if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') { 
            rect.attr('class', '');
        } else { 
            if (totalEnabled < 2) return; 
            rect.attr('class', 'disabled');
            enabled = false; 
        }

        pie.value(function(d) {
            if (d.label === label) d.enabled = enabled; 
            return (d.enabled) ? d.count : 0; 
        });

        path = path.data(pie(infoByHospitals)); // update pie with new data

        path.transition() 
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) { 
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d); 
                this._current = interpolate(0); 
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
            });


        var newTotalCalc = d3.sum(infoByHospitals.filter(function(d) { return d.enabled; }), d => d.count)

        newTotal.text(newTotalCalc);
    });


legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; }); // return label










});
```

2.) *Actual output of the donut chart*:

[image]

3.) JSON file (A small portion)

```
[
 {"hospitalName": "hospital1","diagnosis": "Headache", "females":"1", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital1","diagnosis": "Headache", "females":"0", "males":"1", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital1","diagnosis": "Fever", "females":"2", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "2"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital1","diagnosis": "Salmonella","females":"1", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital2","diagnosis": "None", "females":"2", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "2"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital2","diagnosis": "Chest pain","females":"9", "males":"2", "unknown":"0", "count": "11"}, 
 {"hospitalName": "hospital3","diagnosis": "Concussion", "females":"1", "males":"0", "unknown":"0", "count": "1"},
 {"hospitalName": "hospital3","diagnosis": "Chest pain","females":"2", "males":"2", "unknown":"0", "count": "4"},]
```

Comment: Will each hospital have its own arc chart?

Comment: Hello, @REEE Arc chart meaning "donut chart"? The intended goal is to have each hospital have a donut chart but by updating it only. I'm not trying to create a nested donut chart or multiple donut charts at once. Maybe I can add an image of what kind of donut chart I am trying to make?

Comment: It's because you're setting the data of the path to the whole data array 'infoByHospitals', change it to .data(pie(infoByHospitals[0].values)).

Comment: I see. May I ask what does the code actually do?

Comment: You've set d3.pie to work off of the 'count' variable stored in the data objects you pass it with pie(infoByHospitals). The count variable is actually stored in the individual hospital records whilst the nested data holds no actual count variable, only its values do. That's why you need to set the input data to the values of one of the hospitals with .data(pie(infoByHospitals[0].values)), which is the first hospital in the array, in this case, hospital 1.

Comment: I didn't knew that it would happen like that. I was trying to make a donut chart and populate the arcs with the total count of each unique diagnosis info. Thank you @REEE  So... Once I executed the code, it was able to draw but the arcs are drawn a bit odd. For instance, instead of one single arc of "Headache", there are two separate arcs of "Headache" distinguished by a white line. How can I combine them into one single arc? Maybe through d3.nest()?